# Having trouble with report cmd logging too soon

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I’m trying to make this command so it asks all the questions then logs it inside a channel, what am I doing wrong?

It's sending the "report" as soon as the command initializes. Why is it doing this and how can I stop it?

Here is my relevant code

```js
const theguild = client.guilds.cache.get(config['logging'].logging_guild_id)
    const chantosend = theguild.channels.cache.get(
      config['logging'].report_logs_channelid
    )
    const userId = args[0]
    const reason = args.splice(1).join(' ')
    if (message.channel.type === 'dm') {
      if (message.content === `${config['main_config'].prefix}report`) {
        let counter = 0;
        const embed = new Martinz.MessageEmbed()
          .setColor('#6ccce4')
          .setTitle("Report Form")
           .setDescription('Who are you reporting?');
            if (message.content === `${config['main_config'].prefix}report`) {
          const embed1 = new Martinz.MessageEmbed()
          .setColor('#6ccce4')
          .setTitle("Report Form")
           .setDescription('Explain Why');
            const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
            message.channel.send(embed).then(() => {
            message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 100000, errors: ['time'] })
            .then(collected => {
             let newcol = collected.first().content.toLowerCase()
            message.channel.send(embed1).then(() => {
            message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 100000, errors: ['time'] })
            .then(collected => {
                let newcol1 = collected.first().content.toLowerCase()
            }).catch(e => {});
            }).catch(e => {});
            }).catch(e => {});
            }).catch(e => {});
message.channel.send(embed).then((msg) => {
                  const theguild = client.guilds.cache.get(config['logging'].logging_guild_id)
                  const chantosend = theguild.channels.cache.get(config['logging'].report_logs_channelid
           )})} 
            else {
              message.channel.send('We have recieved your report, please wait while our team reviews it. (This may take awhile...)'
          )
           .then((msg) => {msg.delete({timeout: 25000})
           })
        }              
        const newreportembed = new Martinz.MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle(`**New Report Recieved**`)
          .setAuthor(`${message.author.tag}`, `${message.author.avatarURL()}`)
          .setDescription(
            `**UserID:** \n ${userId}\n **Report Content:**\n ${reason}`
          )
          .setTimestamp()
          .setFooter(
            `${client.user.username} - Built by MLM, Creds to Hyperz n JipyTheDev`,
            client.user.avatarURL()
          )
        chantosend.send(newreportembed)
        console.log(`New report received from: ${message.author.username}`)
      }
    }
```

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to do, you have to implement your awaitMessages() before sending the second (or more) question. The bot will 'pause' only when the awaitMessages() function is executed.

Comment: so with my guilds line where i send it to log inside a guild needs to be b4 the questions?